# The demons assailed me; and fever came, and delirium, to people the waste with shadows. --"to people the waste"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrases, literature

In the following paragraph, I cannot figure out the meaning of the part in bold, and the grammar concept behind that (It comes from the story "Told in the desert"):

> The red demons of thirst assailed me; and fever came, and delirium,
> **to people the waste** with phantasmagoric shadows.

To me it seems as if there was a verb missing between the "people" and "waste". In this context, "waste" probably refers to the desert the character is in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see why you are confused - this is a very un-common usage pattern.

Basically  "to people" a thing means to 'to populate' though in this case this is even more metaphorical, as the shadows mentioned (probably) don't come from anything physical at all - the narrator is describing a dream.

You are correct that "waste" refers to a desert, or similar open ground.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a verb missing, because **people** here is the verb. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/people) has

> **people**
> <sub>VERB</sub>
>
> **1.1** Fill or be present in (a place or domain)
> *in her imagination the flat was suddenly peopled with ghosts*

As you say, the **waste** (wasteland) is the desert.

So the sentence uses **to people** as a transitive verb: in her imagination, the desert was populated with wierd shadows by her fever.